# Doctrine 2 Yaml Driver Not Even ATTEMPTING to Load Classes

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, doctrine-orm

I am attempting to load my schema classes from Yaml in Doctrine 2.0 and I've come up against the wall. Sadly, the Doctrine 2.0 documentation is ATROCIOUS. I thought the Doctrine 1.2 documentation was crap... 2.0 is just beyond words. Wow. Anyway, here's what I have so far:

```
require_once(\config\paths\CLASS_LOADER);
$loader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', \config\paths\PHP_LIBRARIES);
$loader->register();
$cache = new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$driver = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(\config\paths\MODELS);
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driver);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setProxyDir(\config\paths\PROXIES);
$config->setProxyNamespace('lib\orm\proxies');

$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);//@PRODUCTION - set this false

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => \config\db\DRIVER,
    'user' => \config\db\LOGIN,
    'password' => \config\db\PASSWORD,
    'dbname' => \config\db\TABLE,
    'host' => \config\db\HOST
);
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

All of the paths are correct. All of the constants passed to the $connectionOptions array are correct. The models path is a folder filled with files such as ClaimStatus.dcm.yml that contain contents such as:

```
orm\ClaimStatus:
    type: entity
    table: claim_status
    id:
            id:
                    type: integer
                    generator:
                            strategy: identity
    fields:
            name:
                    type: string
            code:
                    type: string
```

Yet after all is said and done and the entity manager is ready I do:

```
$em->find('orm\\Category',1);
```

but all I get is:

```
Warning: class_parents() [function.class-parents]: Class orm\Category does not exist and could not be loaded in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class orm\Category does not exist' in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadata.php on line 67
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YAML driver only takes the path to the YAML files, not to the PHP class files themselves.

You will need to setup a separate autoloader that can find your PHP class files or include them manually. You can probably use the Doctrine autoloader for that:

```
$loader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('orm', 'path/to/orm/classes');
$loader->register();
```

Comment: OK. This is definitely "the answer" to my original question but there's a new issue popping up now. I did some namespace renaming to make it play nice with the autoloader but anyway here's the issue:

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Property "parent" in "lib\orm\classes\Category" was already declared, but it must be declared only once' in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 156**

I don't really see how that is possible. It's clearly only declared ONCE.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm retarded... there was a typo in the YAML. All is well.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this automaically? Or do I really have to include the two lines above for all of my entity namespaces?